# Offline map in React Native Mapbox GL

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

How to properly manage rendering map when device is offline?
Official documentation (https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/API.md#offline) helped to get packs saved and being able to remove them, but trying to load component without network connection gives empty map. `Mapbox.initializeOfflinePacks()` is called in root component and offline packs may be seen and deleted from any point in app.

Other link suggested in documentation (https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/) did not help.

Versions: React Native 0.46.4, React Native Mapbox GL 5.2.0

**Edit**:
This was a bug in our app. Latitude and longitude inside `bounds` argument passed to method `createPack` were swapped so pack was correctly downloaded but contained a map of region that was far beyond visible area at high zoom level and, due to its small size, invisible at wide zoom.

Comment: Any progress on this?